# Only single region in availability check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I have an [uptime check](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks) set up with Google Cloud.

However, I only need this uptime check for a single region as other regions are irrelevant for my project.

When trying to edit the regions of the uptime check and selecting a single region, I get an error saying I need to select at least three regions.

[image]

Is it possible to get around this restriction or get something similar that tells me when my system is not reachable and also lets me view the average uptime for a specific timespan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google Cloud policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#create), you have a minimum of three zone counts for uptime check.   Google Cloud searches from these multiple sources to avoid false positives due to temporary problems in one location. If you want to track downtime from a specific region, Here is a workaround you can consider, although this may incur additional charges.

Cloud Functions / Cloud Run: You can configure a simple HTTP-based cloud function or cloud run service in your specific region that monitors and reports the operation of your service. You can then run an uptime check against this job or service. If you want to track uptime over a specific period of time, Cloud Monitoring can provide that data for you even when used with the Cloud Functions or Cloud Run operations shown above .You can configure Cloud Monitoring  at any time you want. The Metrics Explorer tool in Cloud Monitoring can be used to create charts showing uptime check stats over a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

You must select at least three retions.

You want at least three geo-dispersed sites testing your application. The problem is with only one path, you cannot determine what is down (health check, network path, your app). By consensus of three or more tests, a better decision can be made. Google requires at least three.